# The pair $x_1$ , $x_2$ are Linearly Independent

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are  eigenvectors  with different eigenvalues, then the pair $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent.

The way I went about this proof is by the contrapositive. So I am assuming that the eigenvalues are the same.

For some nonzero vectors $x_1$, $x_2 \in V$, $Ax_1 = \lambda_1x_1$ and $Ax_2 = \lambda_1x_2$ such that $A:V \rightarrow V$ and $\lambda_1 \in R$.

Therefore $x_1 = A^{-1}\lambda_1x_1$ and $x_2 = A^{-1}\lambda_1x_2$ and thus $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be written as a linear combination of each other.

Is this idea correct? Any help would appreciated.

Comment: For contrapositivity you need to show that if the vectors $x_1,x_2$ are linearly dependent, then, $\lambda_1\ne \lambda_2$ cannot be true.

Comment: I think the idea is good but are you sure you can assume the matrix $A$ is invertible?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay I think that is what he is doing, but he's proceeding by contradiction of the contrapositive which is why he assumes the eigenvalues are the same and shows the vectors are not independent.  I think the logic is ok.

Comment: But it sounded to me like he is negating the hypothesis to show negative conclusion. But contrapositive demands that negative conclusion will lead to negative hypothesis. Are these two same, just asking to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assuming that $A$ is invertible here. Suppose $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly dependent, then $x_1=ax_2$ for some $a\not=0$. It turns out that $Ax_1 = A(ax_2)= aAx_2 = a\lambda_2x_2= \lambda_2x_1$, which gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach may be okay, but $A$ may not be invertible as Gregory Grant pointed out in the comments.

One contrapositive approach is to assume that the two vectors are linearly dependent. Then, $\exists c\ne 0$ such that $x_1=c x_2\implies Ax_1=cAx_2\implies \lambda_1x_1=c\lambda_2x_2\implies \lambda_1=\lambda_2$ which is the negation of the hypothesis.